# Category Diagram of a Quotient Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

I am trying to understand the pushforward and pullback of maps in category theory by applying it to groups, kernels of homomorphisms, and quotient groups. Here is the definition of a pushforward and pullback that I am referring to:

[image]

I attempted to create these diagrams to visualize what is going on with normal groups. Below $\pi$ denotes the projection map, $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, $Ker(\varphi)$ is the normal subgroup with respect to $\varphi$, and $\psi$ and $\psi^{-1}$ is the isomorphism between $Ker(\varphi)$ and $G/Ker(\varphi)$.

[image]

Does this even make sense what I am trying to look at, or did I go down a deep rabbithole? This post is also to help check my sanity :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. In this context, pushforward and pullback is terminology applied to morphisms, not objects. Also, I'm pretty sure you want to replace one $\ker(\varphi)$ with $\operatorname{im}(\varphi)$ in any case.

Comment: I am trying to understand how the pushforward and pullback terminology can be applied to group homomorphisms. Also yes you're right, it should be $im(\varphi)$, that makes sense.

Comment: There is no interesting content to pullback and pushforward in the sense given here (which is an eccentric use of those terms); it's just composition. So I'm not sure what you're expecting to find. If $i:\mathrm{ker}\,\varphi\to G$ is the inclusion of the kernel, and $\pi$ is the canonical projection, then $i^*\pi=\pi\circ i=0$, and that's all there is to it.